# Volumes 3-d Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

"Find the volume of the 3-dimensional region with $>0, >0, >0$ given by
$$^2<+<2$$

So I have tried many approaches.

First I obviously figured out the boundaries of the shape. They should be 4 for both x and y and 2 for z.

Then, I worked out that horizontal cross-sections are triangles with area $\frac{1}{2}xy$ and I assumed that we can take isosceles triangles so area is $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ I then took and integral multiplying area by height $$\int_0^4\frac{1}{2}x^2(\sqrt{x}-\frac{x}{2})dx$$

That was wrong.

I then tried to take vertical cross sections of the necessary area between $z^2$ and 2z curves. I figured that they should have rectangular shapes where height is the z coordinate difference between $z^2$ and 2z, width is the distance from x-axis to y-axis which I estimated to $x\sqrt{2}$ or $y\sqrt{2}$ again using isosceles triangles properties and thickness is dx and then set up and integral $$\int_0^4x\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{x}-\frac{x}{2})dx$$ didn't work either.

I have calculated the volume of the pyramid bounded by 2z curve and got around 9.98.

In general I understand that I should take $\frac{1}{2}xy$ and integrate it from 0 to 2 along dz for z^2 and 2z curves but I have a few variables pop up and I don't know how to do it without multivariable calculus.

Yes, just to say. This is a single variable calculus course yet, so I don't think we can use double or triple integrals.

I have a feeling that I go wrong because I assume that we have to integrate along dx or dy axis whether it might not be the case and I struggle to understand how to integrate along z-axis.

Anyways, if you have any idea regarding this one. Would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is supposed to be solved as a 1-dimensional integration problem, most probably [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) is to be used.

- You have already found that $z \in [0,2]$.
- Now, using Cavalieri's principle means, to integrate the area $A(z)$ of the cross sections at height $z$: $\int_0^2 A(z) \; dz$
- Since $z^2-x < y < 2z-x$, $A(z)$ is the difference of the areas of two isosceles right triangles with side lengths $z^2$ and $2z$:

$$ A(z) = \frac 12 \cdot (2z)^2 - \frac 12\cdot (z^2)^2= 2z^2-\frac{z^4}{2}$$

All together

$$V = \int_0^2\left( 2z^2-\frac{z^4}{2}\right)dz=\frac{32}{15}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is correct. Believe it or not I used this approach and it seemed very intuitive for me, however, the place where I stumbled and the reason that I didn't proceed was that I have set the integral another way round, so I had $$\int_0^2(\frac{z^4}{2}-2z^2)dz$$ because on the picture the curved line $z^2$ is above the line 2z and obviously got the negative answer. Can you please explain why are we subtracting this way?

Comment: @YuryMoskaltsov : We consider only those $z$-values for which $z^2 < 2z$. So, the larger triangle has the area $\frac{(2z)^2}{2}$ and the smaller one has the area $\frac{(z^2)^2}{2}$. If you draw the situation into an $xy$-coordinate system, you will see this immediately.

Answer (score 1):

[image: region]

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^4 \int\limits_{y=0}^{4-x} \int\limits_{z = \sqrt{x+y}}^{(x+y)/2} 1\ dx\ dy\ dz = \frac{32}{15} .$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, this exactly coincides with the area I have drawn. Do you now if there are any ways to solve it without triple integral or even double integrals?

Comment: I know of no other way than direct integration.  Why do you seek another way, when this one is so obvious and straightforward????  I suppose you could use symmetry in $x \leftrightarrow y$, but why waste time doing that?

Comment: This task is part of the single variable course and I have not been taught triple integrals yet, but this assignment was given. After spending a few days on this one and Googling I figured that triple integral is the easiest way, but since we weren't taught how to calculate them I figured maybe teachers wanted me to approach it using another method. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: Hmm. Just checked and this answer is marked as false. Also when I put $$\frac{32}{15}(16\sqrt{2}−23)$$ it gives me the answer written above but with the minus sign.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : 
You may want to double check your solution.

Using triple integration you may get

$$\int_{x=0}^4\int_{y=0}^{4-x}\int_{z=\frac{x+y}{2}}^{\sqrt{x+y}}1\;dz \; dy \; dx = \frac{32}{15}$$.

Comment: Oops... yep.  You're right.  Thanks.